# Upgrading from 2008 to R2 didn't update Group Policy Management

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, remote-desktop

I recently updated our domain controllers from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2008 R2.  The main reason for this was group policy.  We had machines in our domain that were 2008 R2 and the non-R2 group policy referred to Remote Desktop as Terminal Services.  There were specific changes we wanted to make to that that we couldn't because of this.

However, after updating to 2008 R2 on the domain controllers the Group Policy Management application appears unchanged.  The setting for Remote Desktop is not under Administrative Templates and even creating a new GPO doesn't have this setting.

Am I missing something, how do I get the updated 2008 R2 Group Policy Management application in my upgraded server?

Comment: Have your transitioned the domain to the higher 2008 R2 functional level? See: [Understanding Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) Functional Levels](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/understanding-active-directory-functional-levels(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Yes, I have raised the funcitonal level to 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using a [central group policy store](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2011/12/12/how-to-implement-the-central-store-for-group-policy-admin-templates-completely-hint-remove-those-adm-files.aspx).

Copy the contents of C:\Windows\Policy Definitions from the newest / most up-to-date server and place them in SYSVOL\domain\policies\PolicyDefinitions.  This ensures that whenever you use the group policy management console it will be reading from the same central set of ADMX policy templates.

When you install updates that create / add new policy definition templates you will need to copy the updates templates to the central store. If you manually add *.admx and *.adml template files these will need to be placed in the central store.

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530196.aspx